# Java - Selenium ChromeDriver - "Chrome Automation Extension has crashed"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://bin/chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
/*Testing ChromeOptions - chrome should open maximised*/
options.addArguments("start-maximized");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
// driver.get(ENM_URL);

driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Opens a new chrome window with a crashed tab, no way to load pages including chrome settings. A toast message pops up saying that "Chrome Automation Extension has crashed"

ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107)

Google Chrome is up to date
Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Chromedriver log file: https://pastebin.com/Gyap7Hft

Answer (score 0):

Pretty tough to debug/analyze the root cause of the error unless you share the error stack trace but while you mention the `System.setProperty()` line, it should be in a proper format i.e. *absolute path of chromedriver.exe* must be specified with the default *path separator* i.e. **`\\`** as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\bin\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Additinally, as you mentioned of using **ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107)**, this version is pretty ancient. The supported version of *ChromeDriver* for **Google Chrome Version 67.x** are:

- ChromeDriver v2.40
- ChromeDriver v2.39
- ChromeDriver v2.38

Inorder to work with **Google Chrome Version 67.x** you have to download either of the mentioned *ChromeDrivers* from [**ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and use them in your script/program.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem. Using ChromeOptions:

```
    options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
```

This argument seems to prevent the Chrome Automation Extension from crashing by disabling it, so the browser itself manages to work and the driver managed to load http://google.com